# Calendar list event cell height does not increase with content

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, calendar

Was wondering if someone knows how to make it so that the cell for the calendar event does not cut off the contents.  Instead I want it to dynamically resize depending on the contents.  I did some digging with firebug and determined that the outer div show below is being set with a height of 16 px.  I do not know where/why this is being set and can't find any CSS in Calendarv4.css/Calendar.css that would be setting it

```
<div class="ms-acal-item ms-acal-selected" "="" _index="0,0"  style="position: absolute; left: 271px; top: 77px; width: 244px; height: 16px; border-width: 1px 2px; z-index: 1;">
<div class="ms-acal-mdiv">
    <a href="/Lists/PpmCalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=1" onclick="EditLink2(this,'WPQ1');return false;">
        <span style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;">
            <span style="width:100%;height:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;border:1px solid Red;position:absolute;color:Black;">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/FamilyCarePRL/Misc/AttachmentIndicator.png" style="float:left;">
                A
            </span>
            <span style="display:inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:Red;text-align:center;border:1px solid;z-index:-1;filter:alpha(opacity=20);opacity:0.2;">A</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[cell cutoff http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/2168/cellcutoff.png](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/2168/cellcutoff.png)

Using the CSS class

```
.ms-acal-item
{ 
    height:50px !important;
    background:none;
    border:0;
}
```

I am able to override the height.  I know using !important is bad but I can't figure out where the height is being set.  Any CSS gurus out there able to lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style is [inline](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm) in this case, set by `style` attribute of the div element. Inline styles have highest priority, that is not a secret. That's why you cannot override the css.

Apparently the `style` attribute for the div tag is generated by ListViewWebPart internally (server-side), and since unfortunately XsltListViewWebPart cannot be used for displaying calendar lists, I can't propose any better workaround here, then to stoop for using some dirty js/jquery hack :(

Sample jquery code:

```
$('.ms-acal-item').css('height', '50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `height:auto!important;` and `width:auto!important;`??? I know this question has been answered, but I'm wondering if that will work instead of a js/jquery hack.